# Strip all non-printable ASCII characters

Tags: code-golf

Your challenge, should you be coded to accept it, runs as follows:

You may choose one of the following two challenges to implement:

**Challenge #1**

- Read from a file `a.txt`
- Write only printable ASCII characters (values 32-126) to a file `b.txt`

**Challenge #2**

- With a file `a.txt`, delete all characters in the file except printable ASCII characters (values 32-126)

**Specs on `a.txt`**

`a.txt` is a plain text file which can include any ASCII values from 0-255 (even undefined/control) and its size can range up to 1 GB.

**Winning**

The answer with the smallest amount of sourcecode in bytes wins.

Comment: @Malachi That's kind of big; how do you suggest I upload it?

Comment: Your winning criterion is wrong. For example I could just. Add a realy lengthy comment to my code, and win.

Comment: @user689 And so it would be if I had an extremely slow program. I assume he meant that least score wins.

Comment: @Malachi but that would mean slower is better, and the question is tagged [tag:fastest-code].

Comment: @amon I'll make it code-golf instead.

Comment: Timtech Are you really sure you want also newlines to be removed?

Comment: Seems a bit late to change the spec, and that's what is currently specified...

Comment: @Tomas You're right, I probably should have thought of that. Oh well...

Comment: examples pls @Timtech

Comment: Should such files actually exist or can "file" be interpreted as "stream", in the sense that we can also use STDIN/STDOUT? Or can we even be more lenient and just accept a string input and return a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### sh

#### Challenge 1, <s>24</s> 23 chars

```sh
tr -dc \ -~<a.txt>b.txt
```

**Bonus**: variations on the set of characters to delete.

```sh
tr -dc " -~
"<a.txt>b.txt                       # preserves printables + line feed
```

```sh
tr -dc "[:space:] -~"<a.txt>b.txt   # preserves printables + whitespace
```

Comment: You can take out the space before `<`

Comment: Right you are! It's just so fugly that I forgot about it. :D

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck: 92

```
+[[->+>+<<]>>>++++++++[->++++++++++++<<---->]>--[<<[->]>[<]>-]<+<[[-]>-<]>[[-]<<.>>]<<[-]<,]
```

Brainfuck cannot open files so you use stdin/stdout redirection (#1)

```
bf strip.bf < a.txt > b.txt
```

The same code in [Extended Brainfuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 68

```
+[(->+>+)3>8+(->12+<<4-)>2-[<<[->]>[<]>-]<+<([-]>-)>([-]2<.)2<[-]<,]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + Perl

#### Challenge 1 – *31* bytes

```
perl -petr/\ -~//cd a.txt>b.txt
```

#### Challenge 2 – *28* bytes

```
perl -i -petr/\ -~//cd a.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, it ran and made the `b.txt` but other characters remain.

Comment: @Timtech cannot reproduce, vim shows no unprintables for me (when looking at `b.txt` of challenge 1)

Answer (score 1):

Both are Challenge 1.

## C - 132 characters

```
#include<stdio.h>
k;main(){FILE*f=fopen("a.txt","rb");FILE*g=fopen("b.txt","w");while(!feof(f))(k=getc(f))>31&&k<127&&putc(k,g);}
```

## Python - 78 characters

```
file("b.txt","w").write(filter(lambda x:'~'>=x>' ',file("a.txt").read()))
```

Comment: Is this Python 3?

Comment: The Python one doesn't work with 3.3.3. Edit: It seems you have to make the file first.

Comment: I ran it on Python 2.7 (r27:82525).

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell (43, 43)**

**Challenge 1: (43)**

```
(gc -raw a.txt) -replace"[^ -x7e]","">b.txt
```

**Challenge 2: (43)**

```
(gc -raw a.txt) -replace"[^ -x7e]","">a.txt
```

Comment: Why not use `~` instead of `x7e`? Also you can leave off the `,""` argument and keep the same effect I believe.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
kPs5ȯ↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kPs5%C8%AF%E2%86%94&inputs=%22regegfer%5Cn%C3%98%C3%B8%CF%80%E2%88%91wodwef2342%CB%86%CF%80%E2%88%86%C3%B8iy%5Cnn%C2%BA%C3%A7%C3%9Ffiwu9few09wf%C2%AB%5B%5C%5Cwe.%3B.%5B%3B%5D.we%5Cn24%22&header=&footer=)

Fixed thanks to Aaron Miller. Why does the printable ascii builtin contain unprintables?

Comment: This should work, but unfortunately, the `kP` builtin contains two unprintables (for some reason), plus the challenge specifies only keeping ASCII 32-126, which doesn't include newlines. The shortest I was able to get it while keeping in line with that range is [6 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kPs5%C8%AF%E2%86%94&inputs=%22regegfer%5Cn%C3%98%C3%B8%CF%80%E2%88%91wodwef2342%CB%86%CF%80%E2%88%86%C3%B8iy%5Cnn%C2%BA%C3%A7%C3%9Ffiwu9few09wf%C2%AB%5B%5C%5Cwe.%3B.%5B%3B%5D.we%5Cn24%22&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

### iX3, 388

```
Set  in [c]:  '1'
Loop start   ([c]  of 1  to 999999999)
   Read from file  'a.txt' into [T] (read from [c], 1 bytes)
   Modify text  '[T]' into [R] (code in Hex)
   Set  in [N]:  '&H[R]' (calculate)
   If  True: '([N]=10)'
      Write into file  'b.txt' line '' (Append)
   End If
   If  True: '([N]>31)&([N]<127)'
      Write into file  'b.txt' line '[T]' (Append, no linefeed)
   End If
Loop end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (52)

#### Challenge #1

```
 IO.write (f="a.txt"),IO.read(f).gsub(/\p{Cntrl}/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 7 bytes

Simple regex to remove non-printable ASCII.

```
[^ -~]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##PVJLTxNRFN77K87a6MKfQEgVkpaa0A0aTcZy294wnanzULsxBSnKs0KgtsXa1kDaUtoGUB5GcWdcfIeF/0D/SD0zJGQmmXPv9zjfPXcc5WnLuDcaPX5Kd18/uTUaTSRiUfKMtEumMrg5p9G2uJKmlINTG50soZW3/xVWueE7pPKKP7s4J@ya2NFzXFJk6ucC@3qWcoa27pCXUeTaVprsFDkK52nfNET5KicsR7muti1hOq4WykttmgJ5WjAr7Ws3E8pf2Dqp3MAgazsCeYZJWcOSTHb22j8wyyhH0SQlBXCVIu2FZd72wyWOuYYyb6OqscDz6HqYxyoXZH8DXRzxdqDQLj1Thu/plG@SF5pSSiZkkmv5qZS@PkbQ0tRK4DBUTNqMRaM0OU3R@LTYlniRy@jyW3zAQeIaE3IIJ0J1zrZwliepknZWjhYUOMXgZhEWAVMnMyK1HcopJ6sMT7YNGVJshu6PjUduvn@/bmUobc@SZdNUXN44vsdFKOVVhVzPzoVuhiV7t3kTl/KcSo0i97iEKvbSvMtLuOQeNnlJovdMrAu2zx0u87KcpIsTNBSKaLrEGwba/I7LDn6IZpG3eFNRYG57wS0XxKSNNYM7Jt7wHi9IuyVUUEeVHo1xEy1e4Xr0wdWaTI0HWPizjKH47eBCWEeUiHNRMlzg2686vvw@wQklJlCJ8CKWuUzcfCj0dfTjqEnPKbyfQYsmJOqK5ClKsw20cI4DDCMSb5cPRFiQm2lzBYfokoS75EO0ZeYdHEmfPobj3Jeb2@cBN3AmEzlGnctxWZYwEKc6r8fEfgs1ceuKuMYfhVOOyFG7vMaSEw00uIpP0zzET2yjI7/XPhfRk1@s/x8)

Test input copied from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2415524).

Comment: I think you're missing the read/write to `a/b.txt` aspect of the challenge

Comment: @JoKing Retina cannot open files. Same as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19411/34718), so it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 122 <s>123</s> bytes

```
set g [open b.txt w]
lmap c [split [read [open a.txt]] ""] {scan $c %c v
if $v>31&$v<127 {puts -nonewline $g $c}}
close $g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY9Ba8IwGIbv@RUvpe6mUGXzMrxsHQiiMPUgNYc0piWQpqGJVRB/e9da3YT2tvv7Pc/3OK4qKxwSRLkRGmzkzg4nSpzMBC7m6CyGOtfipKQW8OtdkhcZcxhwROJsCkRS8wKSDgNKrxi/vhGucttsCbnde@vV9vsjxNd8EbYCj3SclKiMGdRQa5R0iArBDjWDwvNozyP8@qe5FaR3Wvwo6OM9C@9ky5mucU1PSWQCv5xNghe/fA/G0x5v2qh/3WnVFu71Xn@G6818uWsz425m/M/M6gc)

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`b.txt 1:{x@&31<x*127>x}@1:`a.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Above is for Challenge A, replace the `b.txt` for `a.txt` for Challenge B.

```
`b.txt 1:{x@&31<x*127>x}@1:`a.txt / the solution
                         1:`a.txt / binary read (1:) "a.txt"
                        @         / apply to 
         {             }          / lambda taking 1 implicit arg (x)
                  127>x           / 127 greater than?
                 *                / multiply by
                x                 / x
             31<                  / 31 less than?
            &                     / indices where true
          x@                      / index into x at these indices
`b.txt 1:                         / binary write to "b.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 21 bytes

```
{**{31.>}{127.<}m&}f[
```

This can be shortened be replacing the `128` with `'<DEL>` (where DEL is the delete character) but I'm not sure how I can post a DEL here (also replace the `31` and then you can also get rid of the `**`)).

Also, in the WIP version you can golf this down to `:un:ln`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Well, seeing as everyone else is ignoring the requirements to read from & write to a file ...

Input [also](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163514/58974) from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4768433).

```
;oE
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O29F&input=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)

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\P
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clxQ&input=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)